# Display Slider Like control from Database Values

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to display slider like control with Database values, Like below image.

[image]

Is there any control available for this? and How can I make this, 
Database values will between 1-100. I have no idea from where to start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try learning about System.drawing and make your own control, i have done this in the past when i made a custom progress bar, I used [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jHhjhOr6zNE) tutorial on YouTube and it might help you as well.
Also with making your own control you can change anything, get creative.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use `Timeline Chart` ,

[Here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/timeline#SimpleExample) is Google Timeline Chart Example :)